# Google: TypeError: google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The following code throw exception as titled in firefox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
initialize();
});
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you didn't include **Google Map's header**, because your code seems correct.

Try following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

With the newest way to import a library, the `geocoder()` method may not be in the `maps` anymore.

Let say you have the following

```js
  const promises = [
      mapLoader.importLibrary('maps'),
      mapLoader.importLibrary('geocoding'),
    ]

    // Use Promise.all() to send the promises in parallel
    return Promise.all(promises)
      .then(([maps, geocoding, places, core]) => {
        // Return the results as a single object named 'google'
        return {
          maps,
          geocoding,
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {})
```

Then it will be `geocoder = new google.geocoding.Geocoder();`

Answer (score 0):

You should call the constructor after the body has been loaded. `document.body.addEventListener('load', initialize)`

Answer (score -1):

If google map script is not loeaded, and you call map related function then you would get this kind of errors.

Comment: no, if the script is not loaded first you will get an undefined error. the fact that firefox knows it's not a constructor means exactly the opposite, that the script was loaded.